# Clustering Similar Articles Using Mixed Data: Seeking Advice and Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, clustering, feature-scaling, text

Question:
I'm working on a project where I need to cluster a dataset of articles based on various features, including text, numeric values, and categorical data. I've implemented a clustering approach using KMeans and silhouette score to determine the optimal number of clusters. However, I'm looking for advice and validation on my approach to ensure I'm on the right track and to potentially improve its accuracy.

Here's a summary of what I've done:

I have a dataset with features like article title, abstract, DOI, place of publication, authors, citations, recommendations, interest score, and reads.
I've combined these features while properly handling categorical data.
I'm using the silhouette score to determine the optimal number of clusters (K) within a range of 2 to 15.
After finding the optimal K value, I apply KMeans clustering to group the articles.
I've also visualized the silhouette scores over the range of K values.
Despite these steps, I'm unsure if I'm overlooking any critical aspects that could affect the quality of my clustering or if there are better practices to follow. Additionally, I'd like to know if there are alternative clustering algorithms or techniques that are better suited for mixed data.

Could someone with experience in clustering, particularly with mixed data and text, review my approach and provide suggestions for improvement or alternative methods? Are there any common pitfalls I should be aware of? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.